# How to calculate the number of stocks I can buy with X dollars, if we know the exact growth rate of the stock price per dollar?

Tags: compounding

Let's say we have a stock whose price goes up at a rate (from the doubling time formula):

$ r = e^{(\text{volume}/1000 * \ln(1.2))} - 1 $

*(The 1 is subtracted from e^pwr, not from pwr)*

Meaning that it will go up 20% every time 1000 stocks are bought (we assume the sellers are only on the order book offers). Now, if we know that the starting price of the stock is 50, is there a close form solution to calculate how many stocks can I buy with X amount of dollars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get you correctly,

The first unit you buy will increase the price from $P_0$ to $P_0 \times 1.2^{(1/1000)}$, yes? Then, given some budget $X$, you would be looking for:

$\max K$ subject to

$$
P_0\sum_{i=0}^K 1.2^{(i/1000)}\leq X
$$

i.e. a [geometric series](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) where your total number of buys is $N=K+1$.

As [@Alper](https://quant.stackexchange.com/users/47484/alper) wrote in the comment, this is easily solved: Let $G$ denote the growth factor $G=1.2^{1/1000}$, and $P_0=50$ the initial price. Then

$$
\begin{align}
X&\geq P_0\sum_{k=0}^KG^k\\
&=P_0\frac{1-G^{K+1}}{1-G}=P_0\frac{1-G^{N}}{1-G}\\
\Rightarrow N&=\left\lfloor\frac{\ln\left(1-\frac{X}{P_0}(1-G)\right)}{\ln G}\right\rfloor
\end{align}
$$
where we $\lfloor x\rfloor$ denotes rounding $x$ down.

Comment: Yes correct, you understood it correctly. Is there any closed-form solution to this instead of dealing with summation? It would also be enough to be able to calculate the average price at which all the shares are bought. Thanks

Comment: @Hiperfly That Wiki article linked in the answer above has also a closed form solution which is $s =  a \left({\frac {1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}}\right)$. You just need to solve it using also the logarithmic algebra for $n$  which is volume/1000, or the number of shares in thousands, in your case. $s$  would be the same as the amount of money $X$  to be used while $a=50$ and $r=1.2$.